# How to read video format information

Tags: c#, .net, mono

is it possible to "read" Avi or MPEG file format information in .NET ? 
For example: codec used, the video lenght, bitrate and so on ? 
I don't know where to find it into my video....

Thanks

Comment: Either find a library which does it for you, or implement it yourself from spec. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave#External_links

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample application + source code : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/riffparser.aspx . It is in pure c# so you should be able to use it on mono.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, have a look at [Banshee](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/) project (it's a player) developer for **Mono** (compatible with **.NET**).

It uses [GStreaming](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) library, so you may want to look at it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Banshee actually uses [TagLib#](http://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp), which supports a variety of media formats (audio, video, and images).